# Colonial intelligence during the pirate age

Tags: spain, colonial-america, spanish-empire

Watching the [Black Sails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sails_(TV_series)) series, there are several references on [La Casa de Contratación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_de_Contrataci%C3%B3n), and characters say that, among other things, it was dedicated to colonial intelligence.

I think there were a couple of [Casa de Contratación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_de_Contrataci%C3%B3n) agencies. Did either of those really spied on potential threats against the Spanish Crown?

Comment: They were the tax inspectors, among other things. So they spied on their **own** colonies to detect hidden silver mines.